# AngularJS - Check checkboxes dynamically

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to AngularJS. I am working on checkboxlist using WebApi and angularJS and need help. 
Well, there is a checkboxlist where user can select multiple options. I am able to write successful code for this. The selected options are saved into the database. But, on edit, I want those options selected already. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Here is my checkboxlist:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in getCheckboxlist">
    <input ichecklist type="checkbox" id="{{value.Id}}" value="{{value.Id}}">
    <span>{{value.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

Declaration of array:

```
$scope.selection: [];
```

and this is how I am getting selected IDs from database on edit:

```
$scope.selection: selectedValues;
```

where 'selectedValues' contains json of selected IDs.

Comment: Where your ng-models for these checkboxes? you should do this with ng-checked.

Comment: I am not using ng-models. Instead, I am triggering ng-click like, ng-click="toggleSelection(value.Id)". This function gets the selected values Ids for me and I save them in db.

Comment: Ok, you can retrive data from database same way. and add it to value. I will update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are looking for the `ngChecked` directive from AngularJS

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy.

Use it like this

```
<input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="expression">
```

You can replace `expression` by a call to a function that will verify if this checkbox should be checked or not. The function should return `true` or `false`

Comment: Could your mark it as the answer for the future viewer then please

Answer (score 1):

By using ng-checked you can write it as follow

```
//Angular Controller codes
$scope.Checkboxlist = [{id:1, value:  true, Name: "A"}, {id:2, value: false, Name: "B"}];

//View codes
<div ng-repeat="value in Checkboxlist">
    <input ichecklist type="checkbox" id="{{value.Id}}" ng-checked="Checkboxlist[$index].value">
   <span>{{value.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had to change the controller in order to get values in json that I didn't want to. So, I used function call in ng-checked, which worked :) Thanks once again :)